# How to figure out that class is data?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have a data class in my project. It is very very very important to keep this class always as "data" and all his properties must be data classes too (or primitives).

Is there way to figure out programmatically that some class in project is still data-class and it consists only of data-classes which all consists of data-classes etc..?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you need these to be data classes?  What behaviour do you require them to have (or not have)?

Comment: I need to compare 2 objects by "==" operator. Behaviour of comparision is differents depending on type of class - data or not data.

Comment: `==` simply calls the `equals()` method — which is provided in `Any` (such that every object is equal only to itself), but overridden in many other classes (not just `data class`es) to implement e.g. content-based equality.  So it would probably make more sense to check whether the class overrides `equals()`.  Alternatively, you could create two separate instances of the class, with the same params, and see whether they are `==`.

Comment: My data-class is modifying often, it is very annoying to change `equals` method any time it changes. It's more simple to fill my class only with data-classes and compare it by '=='. But some developer could forget about that rule and add non-data class to the model. So I need reflection-based method to check data-classes and just break compilation of project when during build if rule is violated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [Kotlin Reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html). You can check `KClass.isData` and `Class.isPrimitive` methods. It will be something like that I guess:

```
fun isSafe(kClass: KClass<*>): Boolean {
    if (!(kClass.isData || kClass.java.isPrimitive)) {
        return false
    }

    for (property in kClass.memberProperties) {
        val field = property.javaField ?: continue
        if (!isSafe(field.type.kotlin)) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

class Test1

data class Test2(val v: Int, private val t: Test3)

data class Test3(val v: Int, private val t: Int)

data class Test4(val t: Test1)

fun main() {
    println(isSafe(Test2::class)) // print true
    println(isSafe(Test4::class)) // print false
}
```